# Java HW StackOverflowError with Max Subarray pseudocode copied from book

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Im trying to implement a recursive Max Subarray problem with pseudo code copied straight from my book. I cant figure out why Im getting a StackOverFlow problem after 1 recursion. Here is my code.

```
 public class MaxSub {


  public int FindMaxCrossingSubArray(ArrayList<Integer> ar, int low, int mid, int high)         
    {
    int maxLeft=0;
    int leftSum=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=mid; i>low; i--){


        sum= sum + ar.get(i);
        if(sum>leftSum){

            leftSum=sum;
            maxLeft=i;// counter
        }

    }   
        int rightSum=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        sum=0;
        int MaxRight=0; 



        for(int j=mid+1; j<=high; j++){


            sum=sum+ar.get(j);
            if(sum>rightSum){
                rightSum=sum;
                MaxRight=j;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(maxLeft+MaxRight +"max crossing method");
        return maxLeft+MaxRight;


    }






 public int DivideAndConquerMaxSub(ArrayList<Integer> ar, int low, int high){


    if(low==high)//StackOverFlowError 

    return  0;

    else {

        int mid=(low+high/2);
        int leftSum= DivideAndConquerMaxSub(ar, low, mid);//StackOverFlowError 

        int rightSum= DivideAndConquerMaxSub(ar, mid+1, high);

        int crossSum= FindMaxCrossingSubArray(ar, low, mid, high);
        System.out.println(crossSum+ "divide method");
        if(leftSum>=rightSum &&leftSum>=crossSum )

            return leftSum;

        else if (rightSum>=leftSum&&rightSum>=crossSum)

            return rightSum;

        else
            System.out.println(crossSum+ "t");
            return crossSum;

    }

 }
```

I pass in an ArrayList of 2000 ints read from a text file. I also tried storing them in a general Array, but still got same error, so that has nothing to do with it.

I get a StackOverFlow error first on line :

```
 if(low==high)
```

then on line

```
int leftSum= DivideAndConquerMaxSub(ar, low, mid);
```

in DivideAndConquerMaxSub method.

my print out:

```
low : 0

high : 2000

1max crossing method

1divide method

1t



 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at MaxSub.DivideAndConquerMaxSub(MaxSub.java:54)
    at MaxSub.DivideAndConquerMaxSub(MaxSub.java:61)
    at MaxSub.DivideAndConquerMaxSub(MaxSub.java:61)
    at MaxSub.DivideAndConquerMaxSub(MaxSub.java:61) and so on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
int mid=(low+high/2);
```

is wrong. It should be

```
int mid = (low + high) / 2;
```

See if that fixes it

Comment: @Makoto not sure Makoto care to comment?

Comment: Must've seen something else, but I don't see anything else now.  Sorry about that.